# How to get Bitmex API information in real-time

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-tokio

I use the [Bitmex API](https://www.bitmex.com/app/wsAPI) to get real-time transaction information.

I decided to use **tokio-tungstenite** library to get this information

The code generally works, but there are two problems, tokio can't seem to output any information to the standard output stream

```
 tokio::io::stdout().write_all(&data).await.unwrap();
```

I also noticed that after about 5 minutes, the websocket connection to the exchange just closes without explanation (what could it be?) There is no limit for getting real time data, only a limit on connections, which I've definitely done less than an hour.

What is the reason?
Full code here:

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread::spawn;
use std::str;
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;
use tokio::io::{self, AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use futures_util::{future, pin_mut, StreamExt};
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message;
use futures_channel;

struct Bar {}


enum Endpoints {
    Bitmex
}

struct DataAPI {
    endpoint: Endpoints,
    base_url: String,
}


impl DataAPI {
    fn new(base_url: &str) -> DataAPI {
        DataAPI {
            endpoint: Endpoints::Bitmex,
            base_url: base_url.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let base_url = "wss://ws.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD";

    let (stdin_tx, stdin_rx) = futures_channel::mpsc::unbounded();
    tokio::spawn(read_stdin(stdin_tx));

    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(base_url).await.expect("Failed to connect");
    println!("WebSocket handshake has been successfully completed");

    let (write, read) = ws_stream.split();

    let stdin_to_ws = stdin_rx.map(Ok).forward(write);
    let ws_to_stdout = {
        read.for_each(|message| async {
            let data = message.unwrap().into_data();
            tokio::io::stdout().write_all(&data).await.unwrap();
            println!("{}", str::from_utf8(&*data).unwrap());
        })
    };

    pin_mut!(stdin_to_ws, ws_to_stdout);
    future::select(stdin_to_ws, ws_to_stdout).await;
}

async fn read_stdin(tx: futures_channel::mpsc::UnboundedSender<Message>) {
    let mut stdin = tokio::io::stdin();
    loop {
        let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
        let n = match stdin.read(&mut buf).await {
            Err(_) | Ok(0) => break,
            Ok(n) => n,
        };
        buf.truncate(n);
        tx.unbounded_send(Message::binary(buf)).unwrap();
    }
}
```